# Send SMS via Arduino without GSM

Tags: arduino

Is it possible for Arduino to send a message to the internet without using a GSM shield?

I need an Arduino to send a message pressing a push button, which is connected to an Arduino and Ethernet shield, without using a GSM shield.

I need to send a message just by using HTML/PHP API code included in Server via GET/POST. I'm using this code in this code data nicely insert in SQL Database but if successfully insert data send sms via PHP API. But it's not working. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password","db");
  $tag=$_GET["value"];
  $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tag_tbl (tag_value, status) VALUES ('".$tag."', 1)");
  if ($result === false) {
    echo "SQL error:".$mysqli->error;
  } else {
    header("location: https://vas.banglalinksgsm.com/sendSMS/sendSMS?msisdn='xxxxx'&message='".$tag."'&userID=xxxxx&passwd=xxxxxx&sender=WSC");
  }
?>
```

Comment: You could send an email.  There are libraries for that.

Comment: Your question is bit vague. You want to send a confirmation message to a mobile number when a data is inserted to the database ,i think that is your objective.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to send a message to a number when a data is inserted to the database. The best way is to use an online message service provider.

I would suggest you clickatell (which provide some few free messages for testing) , later you can buy api if you want it for commercial purpose. First you need to register on their [site](https://www.clickatell.com/). Then login to it, there you can take SMS integrations. In that there is option to create new integration. Enter a name, desciption,then choose an Environment and API and then go through features settings etc. Then you can choose phone numbers here you can add the test phones to which the sms will be free of cost. Then at last save integration. After that you will get an API key which you can use for message services.This [video](https://youtu.be/d0DH7loGUso) could help you set clickatell API.

Now how can you make it send message?.

You can use it inside your PHP code. The following block of code is enough to send message to a mobile number.

code:

```
{
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=place_your_api_key_here&to=place_your_number_here&content=%20%09ALERT%09%20%0A%0AYour%20vehicle%20is%20noticed%20crossing%20the%20speed%20limit%0A%0A%0ASpeed%20:%20".$speed."%20KMPH" );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch1);

curl_close($ch1);
}
```

You can use it anywhere inside your php code where you want to send message. Edit the `apikey` and `to` in the code as per your api key and your test mobile number. Edit the content portion as your requirement.

```
%20%09ALERT%09%20%0A%0AYour%20vehicle%20is%20noticed%20crossing%20the%20speed%20limit%0A%0A%0ASpeed%20:%20".$speed."%20KMPH
```

The above shown is my content. It send message as

```
Your vehicle is noticed crossing the speed limit
speed: 50 KMPH
```

`%20`,`%09`,`%0A` are various format specifiers to make the message look formatted (Edit them as you wish). `.$speed.` is used to add the speed, send from arduino to PHP code, in the message send to phone.

Comment: This would help you tackle your problem. Feel free to ask if you got any doubt

Comment: Bro your code is not working.. please help. my API Link  is https://vas.banglalinksgsm.com/sendSMS/sendSMS?msisdn='xxxxx'&message='".$tag."'&userID=xxxxx&passwd=xxxxxx when i push button from ardunio tag velue insert successfully but SMS not send. and when i am copy this API link and paste browser address bar and enter then API is working.

Comment: What is Wrong this API its working nicely..  https://vas.banglalinksgsm.com/sendSMS/sendSMS?msisdn='xxxxx'&message='".$tag."'&userID=xxxxx&passwd=xxxxxx&sender=WSC

Comment: Are you accessing your php page from arduino via http request or is the PHP code written inside your arduino code ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `header("location: xxx");` is usable to redirect to a given url. You can Call sms RestApi in simple PHP function to send sms:

```
function CURLsendsms($number, $message_body){
 $api_params = $api_element.'?apikey='.$apikey.'&sender='.$sender.'&to='.$mobileno.'&message='.$textmessage;
 $smsGatewayUrl = "http://springedge.com";
 $smsgatewaydata = $smsGatewayUrl.$api_params;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, smsgatewaydata);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 // Use file get contents when CURL is not installed on server.
 if(!$output){
 $output =  file_get_contents($smsgatewaydata);  
 }
}
```

Also you can use php class to send sms 
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9522-PHP-Send-SMS-messages-with-Spring-Edge-API.html

There are two files in above class:

- **sendsms.php** - Class file to call sms gateway restAPI
- **test.php** - Example file to test sms function.

This Class is using spring edge sms gateway provider API you can customize RestAPI url and params for any other sms provider according to requirement.