# Changing Sender ID for SMS sent through GSM SIM900A

Tags: arduino, gsm

I wanted to inquire if there is a way in which we can change the sender ID of the SMS. I am sending out SMS through the SIM900A GSM Module and want the receiever to have an SMS with ID such as "KFC" for example instead of phone number +92xxxxxxxxxx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a message directly from the arduino, it is not possible to mask your number. But if you want to have another id then you should make use of some message service providers. It requires you to perform HTTP request, thus the GSM module should support that. GSM900A supports http request so you can go for that.I found similar question in [arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=440348.0).

In that you can request for a PHP code which would contain codes for invocation of message services.You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780537/7699452) for more details about online message services.

Comment: But that would require much edit in your current program ( just now i saw your previous question). I think you might have to go on with as it now.